# Is there a formal proof concerning whether a set is (not) the subset of a set containing only that set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering whether there is a formal proof that exists showing that some arbitrary set $A$ is not a subset of $\{A\}$ (though it would be an element)?  It's not clear to me whether this is just a universally accepted axiom of set theory, or if there is a way to prove the relation (or lack thereof).

If it helps, I'd be happy with an answer in terms of the simple sets $\{1\}$ and $\{\{1\}\}$!

Edit: I had forgotten about the empty set!  For my purposes, let's specifically exclude the case where $A$ = $\emptyset$.

Comment: If $A$ is the empty set then it **is** a subset of $\{A\}.$

Comment: @DavidK Conversely, if we have any $x \in A$, then we know that $A \notin A$ and therefore $x \neq A$. So $x \notin \{A\}$, and thus $A \nsubseteq \{A\}$.

Comment: For another start, notice $\{A\}$ has exactly two subsets: $\emptyset$ and $\{A\}$.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thanks for the response!  I think my follow-up is essentially the same as my original question: while I think $A \notin A$ if $x \in A$ makes sense intuitively, is this something that can be formalized, or just taken for granted?  Maybe I'm being a bit too dense here!

Comment: The fact that $A \notin A$ is a consequence of the Axiom of Regularity.

Comment: @RobertShore That works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mark and Robert for the clarification here.  Hopefully this self-answer suffices:

By the Axiom of Regularity, every non-empty set $A$ contains an element that is disjoint from $A$.

Extending this axiom to the set containing non-empty $A$, denoted as $\{A\}$, there exists an element of $\{A\}$ that is disjoint from $\{A\}$.  Since the only element of $\{A\}$ is $A$, it must follow that $A$ is disjoint from $\{A\}$ and $A \cap \{A\} = \emptyset$.  Since $A \in \{A\}$, it must be that $A \notin A$.

Drawing from the above, assume $x \neq \emptyset \in A$.  It follows that $x \neq A$ and therefore $x \notin \{A\}$.  Thus, $A \nsubseteq \{A\}$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Except that if $A = \emptyset$ then $A \subseteq A$ is true.